# Can using 4/5 years averages as regressors cause endogeneity?

Tags: panel-data, autocorrelation, treatment-effect, endogeneity, elections

I have a panel related to political election. Id is **country** and time is NOT the year but the **election event sequentially ordered** (first election in the country, second...and so on), so that you have, in each row, data that belong to different years.

Example: you can have election n.1 in Italy belonging to year 2000 and election n.1 in Slovenia occurring in 2005.

I was wondering whether I can **use as regressors averaged variables** (averages across elections: so that you can have 4 years averages in some cases and 5 years averages in other cases).

My doubt is about **correlations** and **endogeneity** since we have a quite complicated mix of error term entering into the regression at different point in time.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this; this is called an ARMA model (Autoregressive moving average). However, you should make sure to use a good package for time series modeling that includes ARMA models (like R's forecast package), rather than just trying to do this yourself by hand. Otherwise, there's a good chance that any statistics you calculate (like standard errors or confidence intervals) will be incorrect.